# Novel with a hand-held kinetic gas weapon

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a toughie I'm afraid. I read it probably in the late 80s. It was a pulp sci-fi of the classic "tough guy agent bloke does tough guy agent things in space" genre.

The only thing I can remember other than that is that the protagonist had a small gun he could conceal in his palm or sleeve that shot out a sudden burst of highly compressed gas - pretty sure it was a kinetic weapon though, and the gas was used as force multiplier so that he could punch a target in the midst of a punch up and yet the gun would kill them with the "punch" of gas, then dissipate leaving no trace a weapon had been used.

I have a vague memory he used it at some kind of party.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please take a look at our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any additional details you remember.

Comment: Not your knife, but [the wasp knife](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/Science-Fiction-News.asp?NewsNum=1768) has some intriguing similarities.

Comment: I remember the book but only a few more details - fairly confident that the protagonist was the look-alike of someone important in a parallel world that he ended up in.  At least some of the time he didn't kill people by "punching" them but it gave him a reputation for being a ferocious pugilist because of how effective it was when he did hit someone, so he had a nickname along the lines of "slugger" or "hammerfist" etc

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Worlds of the Imperium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_of_the_Imperium)
Keith Laumer

Plot: A man is recruited to travel to a parallel world where his twin has become a ruthless dictator, and replace him.  To help on his mission he is given a gun  like you describe.

[Full text of the novel](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/65792/65792-0.txt) available on Gutenberg.

> I moved my right hand carefully, feeling for the pressure of the release spring that would throw the palm-sized slug-gun into my hand
> with the proper flexing of the wrist.
>
> The little weapon was a marvel of compact deadliness. In shape it resembled a water-washed stone, grey and smooth. It could lie unnoticed on the ground, a feature which might be of great importance to me in an emergency.
>
> Inside the gun a hair-sized channel spiralled down into the grip. A compressed gas, filling the tiny hole, served as both propellant and projectile. At a pressure on the right spot, unmarked, a minute globule of the liquefied gas was fired with tremendous velocity. Once free of the confining walls of the tough alloy barrel, the bead expanded explosively to a volume of a cubic foot. The result was an almost soundless blow, capable of shattering one-quarter inch armor, instantly fatal within a range of ten feet.
>
> It was the kind of weapon I needed- inconspicuous, quiet, and deadly at short range. The spring arrangement made it almost a part of the hand, if the hand were expert.

[...]

> I moved back, dazed, dodging blows. I had only one chance and I needed
> a dark corner to try it. Miche was right after me. He was mad; he
> didn't like that smack on the jaw in front of the boys. That helped me.
> He forgot boxing and threw one haymaker after another. He wanted to
> floor me with one punch to retrieve his dignity. I dodged and retreated.
>
> I moved back toward the deep shadows at the end of the room, beyond
> Chica's pantry. I had to get there quickly, before the watching crowd
> closed up the space.
>
> Miche swung again, left, right. I heard the air whistle as his hamlike
> fist grazed me. I backed another step; almost far enough. Now to get
> between him and the rest of the room. I jumped in behind a wild swing,
> popped a stinging right off his ear, and kept going. I whirled, snapped
> the slug-gun into my hand, and as Miche lunged, I shot him in the
> stomach, faked a wild swinging attack as he bounced off the wall and
> fell full length at my feet. I slipped the gun back into my cuff and
> turned.
>
> "I can't see," a man shouted. "Get some light down here." The mob
> pushed forward, forming a wide ring. They stopped as they saw that only
> I was on my feet.
>
> "Miche is down," a man called. "The new guy took him."
>
> Gros pushed his way through, hesitated, then walked over to the
> sprawled body of Miche. He squatted, beckoned to the man with the
> candle.
>
> He pulled Miche over on his back, then looked closer, feeling for the
> heartbeat. He looked up abruptly, got to his feet.
>
> "He dead," he said. "Miche is dead." He looked at me with a strange
> expression. "It's quite a punch you got, mister," he said.

Comment: Bingo, that's definitely the one I remember, hope it's what the OP is after.

Comment: That is definitely it. "Slug gun" rings a huge bell as does the whole description of the weapon, particularly the pebble-like appearance. Even the name Miche rings a bell bizarrely because the actual plot from Wikipedia is completely unfamiliar :D Thanks so much, amazing identification speed!